# Return the value of container height less 5% for Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

```js
<script id="gtm-hover-listener">
  (function(document, window) {

    var qs = '{{Constant - Hover Listener CSS Selectors}}'.split(',');
    var addEvent = {{fn.addEvent}};
    var removeEvent = {{fn.removeEvent}};
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {

      var els;

      try {

        els = document.querySelectorAll(qs[i]);

      } catch(e) { 

        // If we're in Debug Mode, warn the tester
        if ({{Debug Mode}}) {

          throw 'DOMException: GTM Hover Listener - Invalid Query Selector in variable Constant - Hover Listener CSS Selectors; ' + e.message;

        }

      }
      var k;

      for (k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {

        var el = els[k];
        addEvent(el, 'scroll', bind_);

      }

    }

    function bind_(evt) {
      
      var el = evt.target;
        containerHeight = $('.coverage-content').height();
        mathHeight = containerHeight/95;
        scrollDistance = $('.coverage-content').scrollTop();
        console.log (scrollDistance)
        if (scrollDistance > mathHeight){

      // Fire our push as long as they don't leave in less than half a second
    
        dataLayer.push({
          event: "scroll",
          attributes: {
            element: el
          }
        });

      }
    }


  })(document, window);
</script>
```

```html
<ul class="coverage-content"><li class="n pname">AARP MedicareRx Preferred</li><li class="p"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">AARP MedicareRx Saver Plus</li><li class="p"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured HMO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured HMO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured POS 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured POS 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured PPO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured PPO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Fully Insured PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured HMO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured HMO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured POS 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured POS 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured PPO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured PPO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Commercial Self Insured PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna FEHBP HealthFund (CDHP/HDHP)</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna FEHBP Open Access Arizona</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Medicare Rx Saver </li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured HMO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured HMO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured POS 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured POS 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured PPO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured PPO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Fully Insured PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured HMO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured HMO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured POS 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured POS 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured PPO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured PPO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Fully Insured PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured HMO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured HMO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured POS 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured POS 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured PPO 3 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured PPO 4 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Premier Plus Self Insured PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Value Plus HMO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Value Plus POS 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr><li class="n pname">Aetna Value Plus PPO 5 Tier</li><li class="p"></li><li class="r"><img src="../assets/img/check.jpg"></li><hr></ul>
```

I am working in Google Tag Manager and applying a scroll event listener to a scroll section. The section height will vary based on options selected in drop-down menus.  I'd like to calculate when user scrolls more than 5%.

In some cases the drop-down menus will not produce a scrollable window.  In that case, I need to return a statement that says such.

Here is the current code I'm working with.

```html
<script id="gtm-hover-listener">
  (function(document, window) {

    var qs = '{{Constant - Hover Listener CSS Selectors}}'.split(',');
    var addEvent = {{fn.addEvent}};
    var removeEvent = {{fn.removeEvent}};
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {

      var els;

      try {

        els = document.querySelectorAll(qs[i]);

      } catch(e) { 

        // If we're in Debug Mode, warn the tester
        if ({{Debug Mode}}) {

          throw 'DOMException: GTM Hover Listener - Invalid Query Selector in variable Constant - Hover Listener CSS Selectors; ' + e.message;

        }

      }
      var k;

      for (k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {

        var el = els[k];
        addEvent(el, 'scroll', bind_);

      }

    }

    function bind_(evt) {
      
      var el = evt.target;
        containerHeight = $('.coverage-content').height();
        mathHeight = containerHeight/95;
        scrollDistance = $('.coverage-content').scrollTop();
        console.log (scrollDistance)
        if (scrollDistance > mathHeight){

      // Fire our push as long as they don't leave in less than half a second
    
        dataLayer.push({
          event: "scroll",
          attributes: {
            element: el
          }
        });

      }
    }


  })(document, window);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please also add into your question your HTML markup?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev - Any better?

Comment: No, i mean your html from website. with `.coverage-conten` tag and etc. Now, in your question, i can see only JS function inside your GTM, but i need to see HTML as well

Comment: @VictorLeontyev - I posted the HTML, but if its easier, I'm trying to dynamically calculate the height of the scrollable section on this page - http://livalohcp.com/managed-care-plans/

Comment: Way better, will answer in 15 mins

Answer (score 0):

Based on your goal, your JS should be like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        if ($('.coverage-content')[0].scrollHeight<$('.coverage-content').height()) {
            //datalayer send no scroll
        }
        else {
            $('.coverage-content').scroll(function() { 
                var $this = $(this);
                var state = $('#state-selector').val();
                var firstLetter = $('#first-letter').val();
                var firstLetter = $('#plan-type').val();
                if ($this.attr('datalayer-sent') == undefined)
                {

                    var moreThan5 = this.scrollTop > this.scrollHeight/100*5;
                    if (moreThan5)
                    {           
                        //datalayer send scrolled more than 5%
                        $this.attr('datalayer-sent','true');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $('#state-selector, #first-letter, #plan-type').change(function(){
            $('.coverage-content').removeAttr('datalayer-sent');
            if ($('.coverage-content')[0].scrollHeight<$('.coverage-content').height()) {
                //datalayer send no scroll
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I placed comments, in this JS, where you need to add code, for pushing into datalayer.

**What this script will do:**

It will send datalayer once, if you will scroll more than 5%. And then if you will scroll up and then down, it will not send. But, if you will change filters (state,letter or plan) and then scroll, it will send once again.

Also, it will check if there is no scrolling, it will send datalayer with no scroll message.